# how we use fiter in view.py for multiilngual model in hvad

Tags: django-views, django-multilingual

I am use multilingual for application i developed course application use hvad for that

models.py

from hvad.models import TranslatableModel, TranslatedFields, TranslationManager

class Course(TranslatableModel):

```
translations = TranslatedFields(
    domain = models.ForeignKey('domain.Domain'),
    #track = models.ForeignKey('track.Track'),
    track = models.ForeignKey('track.Track', blank=True, null=True),
    course_nm = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name =_('Course Name')),
    nature_of_training = models.TextField(verbose_name = _('Nature of Training')),
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name =_('Duration')),
    sem = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name =_('Semester')),
    degree_level = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name =_('Degree Level')),
    credit = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name =_('Credits')),
    locations = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name =_('Locations')),
    accessible = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name =_('Accessible')),
    des = models.TextField(verbose_name = _('Description')),
    admission_details = models.TextField(verbose_name = _('Admission Details')),
    further_study_details = models.TextField(verbose_name = _('Further Study Details')),
    seats = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name =_('Seats')),

    title = models.CharField(max_length=512, verbose_name=_('Title')),
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=512, verbose_name=_('Slug')),
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True),
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True),
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, editable=False),      
)
```

IN views.py

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

```
    context = super(DegreeDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    context['courses'] = Course.objects.all().order_by('track')

    return context
```

when i use order_by in views.py so it give following error

**To access translated fields like 'track' from an untranslated model, you must use a translation aware manager, you can get one using nani.utils.get_translation_aware_manager**.

I search a lot but can't find solution, pls help!!
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

It is too late since you asked this question.. but if there is anyone who suffers this kind of problem like me.

I used queryset like this:

`Course.objects.untranslated().prefetch_related('translations').all().filter(translations__track__icontains='lorem ipsum')`

And I recommend not putting ForeignKeys in translations( )